# Javascript: Is there any backdoor way to access the real hidden/private length property of an array?

Tags: javascript

I learned at the [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.arguments) that an arrays length property is a facade. It is an API and not the literal property that holds the length. It acts as a getter/setter to the real length property:

```
"While the getter of the length property simply returns the number of elements that are contained in the array, the setter can be used to truncate the array."
```

Is there any backdoor way to access the real hidden/private length property of an array?

Comment: What for? Why do you think there is "real" property?

Comment: Who says there is any such thing?

Comment: The article implies that array.length is simply a getter method. Is this untrue?

Comment: It describes behaviour, not implementation. I guess, it's really implemented in C code. Anyway, why do you want this?

Comment: "*While the getter … simply returns the number of elements that are contained in the array*" is incorrect. `new Array(10)` creates an array of length 10 and zero members. The *length* property is more sophisticated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea. I'm sure the answer is no, you do not have access to that. I would imagine the reason that `Array#length` is implemented as a getter is solely so that a custom setter can be defined as well.

I'd imagine the internals look something like this:

```
function FakeArray() {

  var _length = 0;

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
    get: function() {
      return _length;
    },
    set: function(length) {

      // some functionality to chop the array
      this.splice(length);

      _length = length;
      return _length;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your logic for believing that *Array.prototype.length* is a getter, or that there is any special hidden alias?

There are various methods that modify the value of an Array's length (*pop*, *push*, *shift*, *unshift*, etc.), so it seems to me that while there may be a setter for assignment so that:

```
var x = [0,1,2,3];
x.length = 2;
```

firstly creates an array of length 4 then sets its length to 2, thereby removing the last two members, I can't see any way that a getter would be more efficient than simply returning the *length* as updated by other methods.

Why would *length* be implemented any other way? And if it was, what is the purpose of this hidden length? And since if implemented it would be completely implementation dependent, how would it be used?

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the problem is that in order to use a custom setter, which in the case of `Array#length` both splices the array and then updates it's length property, you need to use a custom getter as well. Look at my example above and try to imagine how it would work without the getter.

Comment: It may be a constraint of whatever language the javascript engine is written in that a setter for *length* requires a matching getter (e.g. ECMAScript in your answer), however there is no other reason to do so.